# URI is not hierarchical. How to get File Path using getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, deployment, subdirectory

```
private void generateDATFiles() throws Exception {
    File shellScriptPath= new File((this.getClass().getResource("/Vorlagen/Simulation/test.sh").toURI()));
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(shellScriptPath.getAbsolutePath());
    Process p = pb.start();
}
```

So I have a shell script which I want to execute. The problem is that I need the file path and I can get it using `getResource` but I get the error that my uri is not hierarchical so I found out that I need to use `getResourceAsStream` to avoid the error, but my question is how I can get the file path using `getResourceAsStream`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it won't be an easy thing to do. If you pack the .sh script together with the other part of the program in a single .jar it won't work. You can only access it as a resourcestream and not as an URI (even if in development mode you can get the actual URI). That's because the .sh AND the class files and everything is actually in the same file for the file system (.jar).

It's not so much a java limitation as the OS. If the .sh is bundled in the jar/war/any other archive you cannot run it from the java code. (Actually you cannot do it from the command prompt either).

In order to solve it you can get the input stream and write the contents in a temporary file (you can use the java createTempFile functionality) and then execute that one. Or you can extract the .sh file from the jar(zip) and execute it

Answer (score 0):

Try to do with this way.

```
class J{

   public static void main (String a[]){  
   {
     System.out.println(J.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt")
   }
}
```